# How can I determine a webpage's category

Tags: web

Is there any open source project or free avaliable source where I can query a webpage's category type (like https://www.trustedsource.org/en/feedback/url). I have more than 200K webpage in my dataset.

Answer (score 1):

To me it looks like more of a classification problem which is suitable for Machine Learning. For this purpose you can make your model in popular ML frameworks (such as Keras/TensorFlow and PyTorch) or search for available ones on internet and use your dataset to do a transfer learning.

I could find a project on GitHub ([link](https://github.com/domantasm96/URL-categorization-using-machine-learning)) that can be a good starting point.

Answer (score -1):

Hi today and happy weekend!

that's interesting to know if a category is used as category pages, since google shows up multiple spots of one domain when it has category pages.

Examples:
danlok(com)

best example to see: bloomberg....